# Setting up LowDB and testing it using TS-JEST

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am using Node.js and TypeScript for my project and I am having trouble importing `lowdb`. The code below is my `db.ts` file:

```js
import { join, dirname } from "node:path";
import { Low } from "lowdb";
import { JSONFile } from "lowdb/node";
import { DbModel } from "./dbModel";

const { exists, ensure } = require("../src/fsutils");

const os = require("os");

const dbPath =
  process.env.DB_PATH || join(os.homedir(), "/somefile/db.json");

const dir = dirname(dbPath);
let DB: Low<DbModel> | undefined = undefined;
ensure(dir).then(() => {
  const adapter = new JSONFile<DbModel>(dbPath);
  const defaultData: DbModel = { users: [], clubs: [], userClubs: [] };
  DB = new Low<DbModel>(adapter, defaultData);
});

module.exports = function () {
  return DB;
};
```

And this is my `db.test.ts` file:

```js
import { User, AppRole, DbModel } from "../src/dbModel";
const getDB = require("../src/db.ts");
let DB = undefined;
test.skip("Add User", async () => {
  const DB = getDB();

  const role: AppRole = AppRole.admin;
  const newUser: User = {
    id: "1",
    type: role,
    name: "Aleksa Matic",
    email: "aleksa.matic10@gmail.com",
  };

  DB.data.users.push(newUser);
  await DB.write();
  const users = DB.data.users;
  expect(users).toContainEqual(newUser);
});
```

Every time I run the test, I get this error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'` with this detail `({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export * from './adapters/node/JSONFile.js';)`. It is pointing out an error on this line in `db.ts`: `import { Low } from "lowdb";`.

Here are my `devDependencies` and `dependencies`:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@jest/globals": "^29.5.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.195",
    "@types/mime-types": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^20.2.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/lowdb": "^1.0.11",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lowdb": "^6.0.1"
  }
```

I also have `jest.config.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
};
```

How can I resolve this issue?